# What happens when your answer is unaccepted but it is the answer for the OP?

Tags: support, reputation, accepted-answer, unaccepted-answer

I would like to better understand the process of unaccepting an answer.

I want to know if after the OP reads the answer and find that it solves his problem and accepts it (+15). And then he unaccepts it which will induce (-15) and then accepts it again (+15).

But there are just 2 events instead of 3 for that question's Link  and the answer is accepted in the dashboard of the answerer. And the sum of the reputation of the day doesn't  count for this answer.

The person who is the initiator of the `unaccept` will remove it or will be notified?

Comment: I have had this before also.  I usually delete my answer (which may or may not be the approved strategy).  Overall I think you have to suck it up and move on.

Comment: *"the person who is the initiator of the unaccept"* ... that's the OP. I'm not really sure what you're getting at ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is nobody but the OP who can accept or unaccept your answer to their question. There is nobody to notify since there's only one person involved, and he or she will be aware of the action.

I'm assuming you're referring to this sequence of events:

> [image]

In this case the OP initially accepted, resulting in +15. The unaccept the next day caused you to lose the reputation, hence the -15. However, this was later reversed, giving you +15 again, for a grand total of +15 in the end.

So while a -15 is still visible, there is nothing there to reverse, nor anybody to notify of this happening.

Comment: Thank you @Bart for your usefull answer. You understood me clearly. But thing is at then he accepted. But when I sum all the answers for this day , this question is not considered as ((+15)+(-15)=0 which is obvious) even if the answer tag remains.